# Merge two forms in Drupal

Tags: forms, drupal, merge

I have installed the Content Profile module on my Drupal 6 website.

This module lets me associate every user profile with a node so I can use cck fields, ecc

The problem is that when I edit the user profile, the information is divided in two forms: one with the standard drupal fields and the other with the custom fields.

How can I merge these two forms in only one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module Account Profile will do just that. Install it as usual. Configure it in Admin » Configure » Account Profile.

It will put your account edit form on top of your content profile edit form.

Here is the direct link:

http://drupal.org/project/account_profile

Comment: thank you man!!! that's exactly what I was looking for. ANyway, could you suggest me what is the best way to do something similar whithout using any module? It could be useful in some other situations.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think there is a way of doing it without a module. It is possible to use your own custom module, of course. You can check for hook_form_alter and then insert the array of the other form. I don't know in D6, but in D7 you can use field_attach_form.

Answer (score 0):

This post was really useful to me
http://www.thecarneyeffect.co.uk/merging-two-forms-together-drupal